# How do I turn a script which shows orbits into an animation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure

Basically I have the following script which produces a figure showing orbits of planets and I was wondering what the next steps would be in order to make it into an animation as I have no clue...?

I have posted the script below and if anyone could help I'd be very grateful! Thanks

```
clear all
% Set time interval of interest

tspan = [0 165];    % Let ode45 figure out the intermediate times

G = 2.959233074*365*365*(10^-4);% AU^3 M^-1 yr-2 Gravitational constant

ds = dataset('XLSFile','Planetdatayears.xlsx');
M = xlsread('Planetdatayears.xlsx','B:B')'; %masses in solar mass units
xp = xlsread('Planetdatayears.xlsx','C:C')';
yp = xlsread('Planetdatayears.xlsx','D:D')';
zp = xlsread('Planetdatayears.xlsx','E:E')';
xv = xlsread('Planetdatayears.xlsx','I:I')';
yv = xlsread('Planetdatayears.xlsx','J:J')';
zv = xlsread('Planetdatayears.xlsx','K:K')';



%Initial positions and velocities
z00=[xp(1) yp(1) zp(1) xp(2) yp(2) zp(2) xp(3) yp(3) zp(3) xp(4) yp(4) zp(4) xp(5) yp(5) zp(5) xp(6) yp(6) zp(6) xp(7) yp(7) zp(7) xp(8) yp(8) zp(8) xp(9) yp(9) zp(9) xv(1) yv(1) zv(1) xv(2) yv(2) zv(2) xv(3) yv(3) zv(3) xv(4) yv(4) zv(4) xv(5) yv(5) zv(5) xv(6) yv(6) zv(6) xv(7) yv(7) zv(7) xv(8) yv(8) zv(8) xv(9) yv(9) zv(9)]'; %Initial z for 3d

options = odeset('RelTol',1e-10,'AbsTol',1e-10);

[t z] = ode45('ninebodyrhs', tspan, z00, options); 


%The output is a column vector t, with a bunch of times,
% and a matrix z.  Each row of z corresponds to one
% time.  z has as many rows as t has elements.  Each row gives
% the values of all of the components of z at one time.

%Unpack the z matrix into variables you can understand
x0 = z(:,1); y0 = z(:,2); z0 = z(:,3); 
x1 = z(:,4); y1 = z(:,5); z1 = z(:,6); 
x2 = z(:,7); y2 = z(:,8); z2 = z(:,9); 
x3 = z(:,10); y3 = z(:,11); z3 = z(:,12); 
x4 = z(:,13); y4 = z(:,14); z4 = z(:,15);
x5 = z(:,16); y5 = z(:,17); z5 = z(:,18);
x6 = z(:,19); y6 = z(:,20); z6 = z(:,21);
x7 = z(:,22); y7 = z(:,23); z7 = z(:,24);
x8 = z(:,25); y8 = z(:,26); z8 = z(:,27);

%plot the trajectories
plot3(x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4, x5, y5, z5, x6, y6, z6, x7, y7, z7, x8, y8, z8)
title('Planets orbiting the sun in the solar system')
xlabel('x positions')
ylabel('y positions')
zlabel('z positions')

function zdot =ninebodyrhs(t,z)

% This example is "The planets orbiting the sun."

%G = 2.959233074*365*365*(10^-4);% AU^3 M^-1 yr-2 Gravitational constant
G = 4.498572832*(10.^-12);% kpc^3 M^-1 milyrs-2 Gravitational constant
%M = [1,1.660506399000000e-07,2.448266325000000e-06,3.003288829000000e-06,3.227728747000000e-07,9.545296823999999e-04,2.857956803000000e-04,4.365507531000000e-05,5.149983655999999e-05]';

M = [850000000000,200000000,4000000000,1000000000,20000000000,2000000000,...
    1000000000,300000000,15000000,50000000000,114043100.189036,1500000000000]';
%Unpack the column vector z into things one can understand:
%four 2-element column vectors.
%%Positions
r{1} = z(1:3);    %Sun
r{2} = z(4:6);    %Mercury
r{3} = z(7:9);    %Venus
r{4} = z(10:12);  %Earth
r{5} = z(13:15);  %Mars
r{6} = z(16:18);  %Jupiter
r{7} = z(19:21);  %Saturn
r{8} = z(22:24);  %Uranus
r{9} = z(25:27);  %Neptune

v{1} = z(28:30);  % Same as above but for velocities 
v{2} = z(31:33);    
v{3} = z(34:36);
v{4} = z(37:39);
v{5} = z(40:42);
v{6} = z(43:45);
v{7} = z(46:48);
v{8} = z(49:51);
v{9} = z(52:54);

N=9; %Nine bodies


for i=1:N


    vdot{i} = [0;0;0];

    for j=1:i-1

        vdot{i}=vdot{i}+G*M(j)*(r{j}-r{i})./((r{i}-r{j}).'*(r{i}-r{j})).^1.5;
    end

    for j=i+1:N

        vdot{i}=vdot{i}+G*M(j)*(r{j}-r{i})./((r{i}-r{j}).'*(r{i}-r{j})).^1.5;
    end

end


zdot= [ v{1}; v{2}; v{3}; v{4}; v{5}; v{6}; v{7}; v{8}; v{9}; vdot{1}; vdot{2}; vdot{3}; vdot{4}; vdot{5}; vdot{6}; vdot{7}; vdot{8}; vdot{9}];
```

Comment: See: [`VideoWriter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-object.html)

Answer (score 1):

To animate this, you would probably want to create the same plot that you have, just show one value at a time. Be sure to plot `drawnow` after each plot object.

```
% Plot 9 empty plots
p = plot3(nan(9), nan(9), nan(9));

for k = 1:size(z, 1)
    % Update all of the plot objects at once
    set(p, {'XData'}, num2cell(z(1:k, 1:3:25), 1).', ...
           {'YData'}, num2cell(z(1:k, 2:3:26), 1).', ...
           {'ZData'}, num2cell(z(1:k, 3:3:27), 1).')
    drawnow
end
```

If you want to save the result in a video you will want to grab an iamge every time through the loop with [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html?refresh=true) and possibly write it out to [`VideoWriter` object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-object.html).

Comment: Adding that into the script and running I get the following error:

Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line/set
Value cell array handle dimension must match handle vector length.

Error in SolarSystemOrbits (line 55)
    set(p, {'XData'}, num2cell(z(1:k, 1:3:end), 2), ...

Or was I suppoed to change some elements of the code when I copied it in? Sorry I'm really not great with MATLAB graphing!

Comment: @RThompson Can you tell me what the output of `num2cell(z(1:k, 1:3:end), 2)` is and how big is `z`?

Comment: num2cell(z(1:k, 1:3:end), 2) is 1 x 18 double, and z is 845 x 54 double

Comment: @RThompson Ah ok. Your `z` is much bigger than the stuff you plot. I just updated it and it should work now.

Comment: Oh yes I understand that since I only plot the velocities which only go up to column 27.Strangely though, the same error is coming up, may it be due to me having to put the `plot3(x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, etc` somewhere within that code above?

Comment: @RThompson Oh. I just realized that I was using the wrong second input to `num2cell`. You want each column to be used for a different plot so we need that to be 1. Check it now.

Comment: It all seems to be running smoothly at the moment with no errors (the script is still running but I expect it to take a long time as it usually does!) Thanks so much, I would've spent countless hours trying to figure this out to no avail!